# Interrupting and resuming subequations

Tags: math-mode, numbering, subequations

As the title states I would like to interrupt and resume a block of equations that is inside a `subequations` regime. My problem arises when the interrupting stuff shall contain equations on its own:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}\label{eq:master}%
  \begin{align}%
    a & = b \label{eq:master:ab}\\
    c & = d \label{eq:master:cd}
  \end{align}%
\end{subequations}%
%
Some stuff in between
\begin{equation}%
   A = B\label{eq:helper}
\end{equation}
%
Resume here the subequations, i.e., continue with 1c:
\begin{subequations}%
  \begin{align}%
    e & = f \label{eq:master:ef}\\
    g & = h \label{eq:master:gh}
  \end{align}%
\end{subequations}%
Master~\eqref{eq:master}, consisting of~\eqref{eq:master:ab}, \eqref{eq:master:cd}, \eqref{eq:master:ef}, \eqref{eq:master:gh},
and helper~\eqref{eq:helper}.
\end{document}
```

I know how to manually fiddle with the counters, but that is not *The LaTeX Way*. I have seen something like that for enumerations utilizing the `enumitem` package. How would an elegant solution look like, that let me write

```
\begin{subequations}[resume]%
  \begin{align}%
    e & = f \label{eq:master:ef}\\
    g & = h \label{eq:master:gh}
  \end{align}%
\end{subequations}%
```

Comment: Do you want the "stuff in between" without a label?  If not, what label do you want for it?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes As in the MWE: it should be labeled (2).

Comment: @mafp it might be interesting to add this [detail](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225517/subequations-with-main-equation-number) too, which I find very useful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is another method.

I explain: the `subequations` now admit an optional argument. The expected values are  `resume`, `intermezzo`, or nothing. As soon as neither `resume` nor `intermezzo` is encountered, a new potential thread is initialized: continuation goes with `resume`, putting stuff in-between can be anything and if it is again a `subequations` block it has to be flagged `intermezzo`.

The code takes into account that `hyperref` patches  `subequations`.

One caveat: `subequations` block playing in the rôle of intermezzi can not be globally labeled: only the actual sub-equations may be.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

% original amsmath definition
% \subequations:
% \long macro:->\refstepcounter {equation}\protected@edef \theparentequation {\theequation }\setcounter {parentequation}{\value {equation}}\setcounter {equation}{0}\def \theequation {\theparentequation \alph {equation}}\ignorespaces 

% saved by hyperref in
% > \HyOrg@subequations=\long macro:

% hyperref-patched \subequations: (\endsubequations not modified)
% > \subequations=macro:
% ->\stepcounter {equation}\protected@edef \theHparentequation {\@ifundefined {th
% eHequation}\theequation \theHequation }\addtocounter {equation}{-1}\HyOrg@subeq
% uations \def \theHequation {\theHparentequation \alph {equation}}\ignorespaces 
% .


% extending the environment
%   1. with optional parameter: expected values resume or intermezzo or none.
%   2. while keeping the hyperref customization.

\makeatletter
\def\user@resume{resume}
\def\user@intermezzo{intermezzo}
%
\newcounter{previousequation}
\newcounter{lastsubequation}
\newcounter{savedparentequation}
\setcounter{savedparentequation}{1}
% 
\renewenvironment{subequations}[1][]{%
      \def\user@decides{#1}%
      \setcounter{previousequation}{\value{equation}}%
      \ifx\user@decides\user@resume 
           \setcounter{equation}{\value{savedparentequation}}%
      \else  
      \ifx\user@decides\user@intermezzo
           \refstepcounter{equation}%
      \else
           \setcounter{lastsubequation}{0}%
           \refstepcounter{equation}%
      \fi\fi
      \protected@edef\theHparentequation{%
          \@ifundefined {theHequation}\theequation \theHequation}%
      \protected@edef\theparentequation{\theequation}%
      \setcounter{parentequation}{\value{equation}}%
      \ifx\user@decides\user@resume 
           \setcounter{equation}{\value{lastsubequation}}%
         \else
           \setcounter{equation}{0}%
      \fi
      \def\theequation  {\theparentequation  \alph{equation}}%
      \def\theHequation {\theHparentequation \alph{equation}}%
      \ignorespaces
}{%
%  \arabic{equation};\arabic{savedparentequation};\arabic{lastsubequation}
  \ifx\user@decides\user@resume
       \setcounter{lastsubequation}{\value{equation}}%
       \setcounter{equation}{\value{previousequation}}%
  \else
  \ifx\user@decides\user@intermezzo
       \setcounter{equation}{\value{parentequation}}%
  \else
       \setcounter{lastsubequation}{\value{equation}}%
       \setcounter{savedparentequation}{\value{parentequation}}%
       \setcounter{equation}{\value{parentequation}}%
  \fi\fi
%  \arabic{equation};\arabic{savedparentequation};\arabic{lastsubequation}
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{subequations}\label{eq:master}
  \begin{align}
    a & = b \label{eq:master:ab}\\
    c & = d \label{eq:master:cd}
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}
%
Some intermezzo stuff in between
\begin{equation}
   A = B\label{eq:helper}
\end{equation}
%
\begin{subequations}[intermezzo]
  \begin{align}
    C &= D\label{eq:inter1}\\
    E &= F\label{eq:inter2}
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}
Resume here the subequations, i.e., continue with 1c:
\begin{subequations}[resume]
%  \label{eq:Master} % NO! impossible here
  \begin{align}
    e & = f \label{eq:master:ef}\\
    g & = h \label{eq:master:gh}\\
    g & = h \label{eq:master:gh2}
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}
Master~\eqref{eq:master}, consisting of~\eqref{eq:master:ab},
\eqref{eq:master:cd} and \eqref{eq:master:ef}, \eqref{eq:master:gh},
\eqref{eq:master:gh2} 
and helpers \eqref{eq:helper}, \eqref{eq:inter1} and \eqref{eq:inter2}. But one
can not label the intermezzo block, only its subequations.

Some more continued stuff:
\begin{subequations}[resume]
  \begin{align}
    i & = j \label{eq:master:ij}\\
    k & = l \label{eq:master:kl}\\
    i & = j \label{eq:master:ij2}
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}
and we re-initialize again (resuming will continue from here):
\begin{subequations}
  \begin{align}
    A &= B\label{eq:final1}\\
    B &= A\label{eq:final2}
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}
Two intermezzi (my head starts spinning!):
\begin{subequations}[intermezzo]
\label{eq:Intermediate}
  \begin{align}
    A &= B\label{eq:final3}\\
    B &= A\label{eq:final4}
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}
  \begin{align}
    A &= B\label{eq:final5}\\
    B &= A\label{eq:final6}
  \end{align}
And we resume again (some aspirin please!)
\begin{subequations}[resume]
  \begin{align}
    A &= B\label{eq:final7}\\
    B &= A\label{eq:final8}
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}

So we had a new block of subequations \eqref{eq:final1}, \eqref{eq:final2},
\eqref{eq:final7}, and \eqref{eq:final8}; and in-between there were
\eqref{eq:final3}, \eqref{eq:final4}, \eqref{eq:final5}, and \eqref{eq:final6}.

\end{document}
```

[image: intermezzi and resumed enumaration]

Answer (score 8):

My solution provides a second environment `subequations*` that picks up the values from the last `subequations` or `subequations*` environment.
The `\end{subequations}` part is redefined to save the values of the counters (in this case `1` and `2` = `b`) in auxiliary counters. These are used in the `subequations*` environment.

*Note:* It is the possible to label the `subequations*` environments which means that there will be more than one “Master” equation. This is gets interesting when you use a `\pageref`.

The reason for `etoolbox`’ `\patchcmd` macor can be read [in another answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/80146/16595). Short version: The `\theparentequation` macro is defined independently from the `parentequation` counter.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{qrr@oldeq}
\newcounter{qrr@oldsubeq}
\newcounter{qrr@realeq}
\renewenvironment{subequations}{%
  \refstepcounter{equation}%
  \protected@edef\theparentequation{\theequation}%
  \setcounter{parentequation}{\value{equation}}%
  \setcounter{equation}{0}%
  \def\theequation{\theparentequation\alph{equation}}%
  \ignorespaces
}{%
  \setcounter{qrr@oldeq}{\value{parentequation}}%
  \setcounter{qrr@oldsubeq}{\value{equation}}%
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{parentequation}}%
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\newenvironment{subequations*}{%
  \setcounter{qrr@realeq}{\value{equation}}%
  \let\theparentequation\theequation%
  \patchcmd{\theparentequation}{equation}{parentequation}{}{}%
  \setcounter{parentequation}{\numexpr\value{qrr@oldeq}-1}%
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{qrr@oldsubeq}}%
  \def\theequation{\theparentequation\alph{equation}}%
  \refstepcounter{parentequation}%
  \ignorespaces
}{%
  \setcounter{qrr@oldeq}{\value{parentequation}}%
  \setcounter{qrr@oldsubeq}{\value{equation}}%
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{qrr@realeq}}%
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}\label{eq:master}%
  \begin{align}%
    a & = b \label{eq:master:ab}\\
    c & = d \label{eq:master:cd}
  \end{align}%
\end{subequations}%
%
Some stuff in between
\begin{equation}%
   A = B\label{eq:helper}
\end{equation}
%
Resume here the subequations, i.e., continue with 1c:
\begin{subequations*}\label{eq:Master}
  \begin{align}%
    e & = f \label{eq:master:ef}\\
    g & = h \label{eq:master:gh}
  \end{align}%
\end{subequations*}%
Master~\eqref{eq:master}, consisting of~\eqref{eq:master:ab}, \eqref{eq:master:cd} and \eqref{eq:master:ef}, \eqref{eq:master:gh} from Master \eqref{eq:Master},
and helper~\eqref{eq:helper} and final~\eqref{eq:final}.

Some stuff at the end:
\begin{equation}%
   A = B\label{eq:final}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Good solution, but I find it very confusing to the reader.

Comment: I agree on both counts that solution is excellent but that presentation is confusing to reader.  It would be less so if the stuff in between were unlabeled, but then it could not be referenced.

Comment: @egreg But consider the possibility that the subequations carry a special main tag, and it won't be confusing.

Comment: This code produces `warning  (pdf backend): ignoring duplicate destination with the name 'equation.xxx'` messages in the terminal. They are suppressed by moving the `hyperref` import to _after_ the `\newenvironment{subequations*}{ ... }`, but this is quite inconvenient for those who organise their preamble with package imports first and definitions second.

Answer (score 1):

I found a practical solution for resume some subequations between some stuff. I use the `\tag{}` option but I include into the tag the `\ref{}` option like this:

```
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
\rm\displaystyle \tan\upgamma&=\frac{\upeta_r}{1-(\upomega/\upomega_r)^2} \\
\rm\displaystyle \tan(90^{\circ}-\upgamma)&=\tan\left(\frac{\uptheta}{2}\right)=\frac{1-(\upomega/\rm \upomega_r)^2}{\upeta_r}
\end{align}
\label{eq:1}
```

some text or whatever you want

```
begin{equation}
\rm\displaystyle \upomega^2=\upomega_r^2\left(1-\upeta_r\tan\left(\frac{\uptheta}{2}\right)\right)\tag{\ref{eq:1}c}
\label{eq:ewins_4_6_c}
\end{equation}
```

I know this is not the `\LaTeX{}` way but is very practical